# AJAX success return array and want to set this in drop-down

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I am calling a php function using ajax.
It works and i got a `php array` in ajax success.
like.

> Array
>       (
>       [0] => Array
>       (
>       [calendarId] => 1
>       [calendarName] => Calendar One
>       )
>
> ```
> [1] => Array
> (
> [calendarId] => 2
> [calendarName] => Calendar Second
> )
> )
>
> $.ajax({
>    url:"data.php",
>    success:function(data){
>       console.log(data);
> }
> });
> ```

I want to set this array in to a drop-down.
how can I set this php array in to drop-down using jquery AJAX success event.

Comment: _how can i set this php array in to drop-down using jquery ajax success event_..... what is it exactly?

Comment: i think you should use `json_encode(array)` to generate response in json.

Comment: sorry but forget to add `dataType:"Json"` for this its return me data as a string :P

Answer (score 1):

```
var li="";
      $.ajax({
           url:"data.php",
           success:function(data){
              console.log(data);
    li+='<option>'+data[i].value+'</option>';

        }
    $('select').append(li);
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<select id="yourSelect"></select>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        var customArray = ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"];
        var option;

        for (i = 0; i < customArray.length; i++) {
            option = $("<option/>", { value: customArray[i], html: customArray[i] });
            $("#yourSelect").append(option);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var selOpts = "";
 for (i=0;i<data.length;i++)
 {
        var id = data[i]['calendarId'];
        var val = data[i]['calendarName'];
     selOpts += "<option value='"+id+"'>"+val+"</option";
 }
  $('#selectDropdownSelector').append(selOpts);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the options of the dropdowns from the array that you are getting in the following way

If type is JSON use data.d

```
 success:function(data){
      for (i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
            option = $("<option/>", { value: data.d[i], html: data.d[i] });


            $("#selectList").append(option);

            //OR

            option.appendTo($("#selectList"))
        }
 }
```